# NodeJS await all url-exists before returning

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm having an issue of my controller returning data before `url-exists` finishes running.

```
const urlExists = require('url-exists');
const ESAPI = require('node-esapi');

exports.getDocs = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const id = req.params.tID;

        let docs = [];
        const getDocs = await models.Documents.getDocs(id); // Getting data from Database
        for(const d of getDocs) {
            const docName = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(d.DocumentName);
            const path = `https://mywebsite/Files/${id}/${docName}`;
            urlExists(path, function(err, exists) {
                    console.log(exists);
                if(exists) {
                    docs.push({
                        path,
                        audited: d.Audited,
                        comment: d.Comment
                    });
                }
            });
        }
            console.log(docs);
        return res.json(docs);
    } catch(err) {
        return res.json([]);
    } 
}
```

I can see in the `console.logs()` that it first logs the `console.log(docs);` an empty array. Then, it logs the `console.log(exists)`. How can I wait until the for loop and `urlExists` finishes running before returning the `docs` array?

Thanks

Comment: that is a very old package, try to use [this newer instead](https://github.com/Richienb/url-exist) as it adds support for the `await`, just as it's said in a PR never merged - https://github.com/boblauer/url-exists/pull/4#issuecomment-603972443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urlExists` is a callback-based function, you can promisify it and then `await` it.

To promisify `urlExists` function, you can use built-in node module: [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

```
// import the "util" module
const util = require('util');

// create a promise wrapper around "urlExists" function
const promisifiedUrlExists = util.promisify(urlExists);
```

After `urlExists` has been promisified, `await` it inside the loop.

```
exports.getDocs = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        ...

        for(const d of getDocs) {
            ...

            const exists = await promisifiedUrlExists(path);

            if(exists) {
               docs.push({
                  path,
                  audited: d.Audited,
                  comment: d.Comment
               });
            }
        }

        return res.json(docs);

    } catch(err) {
        return res.json([]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Do you mind explaining the ```util``` library?

Comment: Its a built-in node module, check its details [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v15.x/api/util.html)